# How can I translate a song originally written for 5 octaves to be playable with only 3 octaves while still sounding good?

Tags: midi, octave

I'm working on a script to translate midifiles into button presses in a game (scum) where I can play an instrument. However, the game only allows me to play with 3 octaves. As someone with no background in music theory, I'm wondering if it's possible to play a song originally written for 5 octaves with only 3, and if so, how I can go about doing it. Would the song still sound good with this change? Any tips or suggestions on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Many songs feature a distinction between a "melody" line and "harmony," supporting chords. It would be rare for a melody to span 5 octaves. You could focus on keeping the melody "intact," and compress the underlying harmony.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to adapt sheet music so I can play with my 61 note keyboard](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/124656/how-to-adapt-sheet-music-so-i-can-play-with-my-61-note-keyboard)

Comment: I'm trying to think through how you could do this automatically and get sensible results. It occurs to me that it's rather specific that you're looking to shrink the range from exactly five octaves - that makes me think you're trying to use MIDI files from a particular repository or collection. Is that so, and if so, what is it? Although Aaron's answer is correct in general, there might be some specific structure you can take advantage of in the particular MIDI you're using.

Answer (score 1):

The answer will vary from song to song. It's wholly depending on the specific details of the music, and it typically requires rearranging or even recomposing parts of the song. In some places it might work simply to lower the octave; in others it might be necessary to write entirely new music.

This is a problem that composers/arrangers run into routinely when attempting to adapt music to a particular instrument and stay within that instrument's limitations. **This can't be done with a script.**